# an asp,net controll send ajax request

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm having difficulties to find a good explanation and tutorial 
on how to send an ajax request from one asp.net control (when clicking on an item in its )
to update from the server another control.

Is UpdatePanel is the only solution- and does it really avoid a postback?

I'll be thankful for any useful link,

Comment: No, UpdatePanel is not the only solution.  Additionally, what do you mean by "to update from the server another control"?  What specifically are you trying to do?  You might not even need AJAX (or any server-side involvement) for this if you're just manipulating page elements.

Answer (score 0):

Personally ASP.net AJAX is not my favorite thing to use. This is diferent to Microsoft AJAX Library.
When you use ASP.net AJAX you are not refreshing the whole page, but the whole page is processed again in the server and in many cases you dont need this. Sometimes you just need one line of text to be changed.

For all these cases I prefer to use JQuery with ASP.net webservices or page web methods.
If you want to refresh the content of the user control using this technique I would consider taking a look at this [Blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx) from ScottGu, I've been using this idea successfully.

Answer (score 0):

An easy alternative is [Page Web Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28VS.71%29.aspx)